# Android: Multiple Fragments from same XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a view pager that has a page for each subject in an array (English, Maths, Science, etc). The fragments in the view pager are all created from the same XML file. These fragments then have fragments added inside of them.
As all the parents inflate from the same XML file, I can not specify which fragment I want to add the child fragment to. I was wondering if their was a way to do this - Narrow the scope of the id maybe??

Comment: I am doing something similar, like having unique view pager for the tab like pages. I say that there is nothing wrong having a fragment for each XML file. In code, you can inflate the fragment xml when user select the subject, English and Math).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean that it is ok to just create a different xml file for each page in the view pager, and just give the frame layout in the xml file a different ID.

Comment: Yes AcademicDuck, it's fine. I certainly don't see any advantage of having the parent-child relationship among fragments. If anything, that would make things complicated, do it if you want to get MS degree in Fragments, haha.

Comment: The reason for the parent-child relationship is because in the view pager, I want to display the modules for each subject, in a recycler view. When a module is clicked, the recycler view changes, to display the topics in that module. That all works fine, but I cannot add the change to the recycler view to the back stack, so I thought I could change the whole fragment when a recycler view item was clicked. Then I could add that to the back stack.

Comment: I think it's fine that you specified the fragments in one XML. But the UI elements can be specified in separate XML, for clarity. I have not implemented multiple fragments yet. But I will post an answer that may be promising for you. And perhaps you have not tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to implement multiple fragments with the capability to manipulate them depending on user selections. There is Google link [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Review these code on that web page:

1. The many samples of `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction`
2. Look at method `showDetails` in class `TitlesFragment`, for example.

If you want a working sample, look at [Working with Android Fragments](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/). Snippet from the webpage:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/headFrag"
    android:name="com.intertech.HeaderFrag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/bodyFrag"
    android:name="com.intertech.BodyFrag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code

```
...
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
    // work here to change Activity fragments (add, remove, etc.).
    fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.myFrame, myFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit ();
```

From above, notice there are 2 fragments in the layout. And fragmentTransaction.add method should specify parent container in R.id form.

Someday I may want/need to implement this. So far I implemented show/hide `Layouts` instead (not regretting it), and they can have IDs for me to manipulate.
Have fun and keep us posted,  Tommy Kwee.

Comment: I have managed to get it working. I set the is of the frame layout, that I was trying to add the fragment to, to be View.generateViewId(). I then called frame.getId() when I wanted to add a fragment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will TRY to remember your technique since it works for you. Although I think my suggested technique is encouraged by Google (disagree with me if you like). Congrats in getting your code to work, does not seem easy.

Answer (score 0):

First. I suggest you to try to avoid child fragment, if you really doesn't have very good reason to use them.

But I don't understand where is problem. I don't see any problem if more fragment use the same XML for the inflate. You can call `setArguments()` on all parent fragment and put here some Bundle which can be used to recognize which fragment it is inside of it by `getArguments()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although, I am unsure on how this would help. I am trying to add a child fragment inside the parent by using a frame layout inside the XML. When I try and reference this layout in the method fragmentTransaction.add(), It just puts it in the first fragment in the view pager.